# Bone envelope changes without reparenting

Tags: animation, armature

When a set of bones are parented to a mesh (Ctrl+P > Automatic > With Envelope Weights), you can then change the Bone>[Deform](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/armatures/bones/properties/deform.html) envelope settings.

These settings, however, seem to have no effect until the armatures are unparented and then parented again.

What's going on, and is there a better way to make an armature deform a mesh and be able to alter the envelope settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*From the manual*

**[With Envelope Weights](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/armatures/skinning/parenting.html#with-envelope-weights)**

> Works in a similar way to With Automatic Weights. The difference is
>   that the influences are calculated based on the Bone Envelopes
>   settings. It will assign a weight to each vertex group the vertices
>   that is inside its bone’s influence volume, depending on their
>   distance to this bone.
>
> This means newly included/excluded vertices or new envelope settings
>   will not be taken into account. You will have to apply Armature Deform
>   With Envelope Weights parenting again.

*And in particular*

> **Tip**
>
> If you want the envelope setting to be used instantly, bind the
>   [Armature Modifier to Bone Envelopes.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/armature.html#bind-to)

[image]